# Variation of Farkas’ Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Given matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$, and $H \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times n}$, I want to prove that exactly one of the following 2 systems has a solution:

1. $Ax < 0$, $Bx \leq 0$, and $Hx = 0$
2. $A^{T}u + B^{T}v + H^{T}w = 0, u \geq 0, v \geq 0, e^{T}u = 1$ where $e^{T}$ is a column vector of length m such that every entry of the column vector is 1.

So far I proved that both cannot be simultaneously satisfied by using one of the Corollary from Farkas’ lemma. However, I am stuck at showing that one of them must be satisfied (i.e. I am trying to prove that if 1) is not satisfied, then 2) must be satisfied).

Could anyone help me with this question here?

Thank you!!

Comment: May I ask why you think the statement is true?

Comment: Honestly I don't have good intuition on why this holds or why this is false. It will be greatly appreciated if someone is able to prove this identity or disprove with some counterexample and intuition. Thanks!!